# Volume control of AVAudioPlayer instance

Tags: ios, swift, avaudioplayer

I am making a background audio for my current App.
The audio is playing by initializing a AVAudioPlayer instance, like the following code:

```
var audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer()
```

I have been reading the AVAudioPlayer's documents.

My question is : how to mute/unmute the audioPlayer and it is still playing in the background? Should I do it via volume control or any function that can swift on and off audio instantly?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The volume will be controllable by the person's volume buttons on the side of their device or you can set the volume via the `volume` property if you have a UI control visible for the person to mute it with.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avaudioplayer/1389330-volume